# Regex: How do I replace part of a pattern and reference a variable within it?

Tags: regex, vi, replace

I want to match a pattern, replace part of the pattern, and use a variable within the pattern as part of the replacement string.

Is this correct?

`/s/^((\s+)private\sfunction\s__construct\(\))/(2)def\s__init__`

In English: Replace any amount of whitespace followed by the string `"private function __construct()"` with the same amount of whitespace and the string `def __init__`.  So, is my regex bad or what?

[image: partial replace]

Comment: What language/application are you using this in?  (Not the language your data is in.  The one that is executing the expression.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called a backreference, and you use `\i` to refer to the i'th captured group from the pattern.

So for the pattern `^((\s+)private\sfunction\s__construct\(\))`, the replacement is `\2def __init__`.

Comment: Okay, but here's another example: `:s/^((\s+)$this->).*$/\2self./`.  As you can see, I'm searching for `^(\s+)this->.*$`, right?  But I only want to replace this part of the search pattern: `\s+this->`.  So, I used two sets of brackets....  Should I reference `\2` or `\1`?

Comment: The capturing brackets are counted left-to-right, so `\1` for that example. Since this is in vi, you have to escape bits of the regular expression, see @PrashantBhate's answer. Either that or I use the `\v` flag in vim to use normal regex syntax, but I'm not sure if vi has it.

Answer (score 14):

I presume you want to replace it in `vi`

Replace all occurrences

```
:s/^\(\s\+\)private function __construct()/\1def __init__/g
```

Replace first

```
:s/^\(\s\+\)private function __construct()/\1def __init__/
```

Few suggestions to your pattern

- `/` is used in `vi` for search , use `:`
- you need to escape `(` `)` in vi
- use `\i` where i is xth capture group like `\1` `\2` to back reference grouped patterns in replacement
- `\s` can not be used in replacement text use `' '` instead
- use trailing `/g` if you want to replace all occurrences

http://vimregex.com should help you get started.

Comment: But here's an issue....  If I have `{$\n\r      replaceme`, I want to search for `{$\n\r\s+replaceme^`, and I only want to replace `\s+replaceme`.  The reason I want to do this is because there are times when "      replaceme" isn't preceded by `{$\n\r`, and I don't want the command to activate on those.  So, can I replace "      replaceme" only when it's preceded by `{$\n\r`, and start my replacement with the same amount of whitespace?

Comment: Many thanks for the link to http://vimregex.com/. What a great page! :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think anyone really understood the question.  Basically, the way I'm doing this is as follows:

"If you want to search for a replacement pattern, pattern a, and replace it with a replacement string, pattern i, only if it starts with a pattern, pattern b, then you need to include pattern b in the replacement string, like this: :/(pattern b)(pattern a)/(pattern b)(i)/g".

It's a little wordy but worth reading.

In the past, I'm sure that someone has thought, "It could save a lot of resources to not actually replace `pattern b` with `pattern b`. It's redundant to do so."  Maybe it happens automatically.  I haven't found a built-in method in vi or any other program to do that.  I'm sure I could write a script to do it, though.