# Insert and edit comments in c

Tags: c, doxygen

Now I have a bunch of C source files with already inserted comments, which are in format `/*****......*****/` for functions and `/*....*/` for phrases and variables. My task is to document these files with doxygen. The problem is obvious: the comment formats are not supported by doxygen. So I have to find a way to modify the comment format of the files and also add other further comments.

I've tried with gvim with doxygen toolkit. I was only able to insert something simple like

```
/**
* @brief 
*/
```

only to functions. So I'm wondering if there's a way for me to modify the already existing comments. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Of course you can modify the existing comments. Are you asking if there's an automated tool to do it?

Comment: You need to modify the existing comments!

Comment: Have you considered/tried any shell command/script approach like using grep/awk etc? Perhaps its difficult in vim without a plugin but much easier with grep/awk/sed specially for a bunch of files. It also depends on the existing command layout. E.g. if between /****** and *****/ there is single or multi-line text etc.

Comment: Yes that's my question. A tool (an editor like vim, a compiler like eclipse) which has such function.

Comment: It looks like you're looking to take an arbitrary, non-standard, non-supported format, and automatically convert it to Doxygen-style? That doesn't seem likely -- you'll have to use some tools like @alienfromouterspace suggests most likely.

Comment: You can use Perl, or Python with regex to do such a work in an automated way.

Comment: @alienfromouterspace  thanks for the suggestion. I'll see what can I find.

Comment: @daouzli Thank you for the suggestion. I'll try with Python for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Vim:

```
\/\*\*\*\*\*\_.\{-}\*\*\*\*\*\/
```

Finds

```
/*****
abcdef
*****/
void main()
{
    int a = 0;
    /**** abcdef ****/
}

/***** abcdef *****/
void function()
{
}

/*****
abcdef
abcdef
abcdef
*****/
void function2()
{
}
```

Which can easily be convert to a sub expression replacement VIM command:

```
:1,$ s/\(\/\*\*\*\*\*\)\(\_.\{-}\)\(\*\*\*\*\*\/\)/\/\*\*\2\*\//g
```

:)
Perhaps python/grep-awk would be a better choice here!

EDIT: Comment - Above solution is strictly based on the /***** pattern (i.e. number of '*' in /*****)

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution! Actually I'm trying with search and replace of vim too! However I did't get a good result. For example for a comment like /*abcdef*/ I want to change it like /**abcdef*/, I used the command :s#/*#/**#g, and that's not correct

Comment: And I understand that you use '\' to escape the '/', but for every * there should be a '\'? and I either don't understand the (\_.\{-}\) part, also the '1' at the begining. Could you explain me that?

Comment: \\_. Matches any new line and character, \{-} makes the match non greedy (a restricted version of *... If you create sub patterns using () in your regex then in substitute you can use parts by referring them as \1, \2 etc \0 denotes a full matched string (ignoring sub pattern) here is a similar discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904068/regex-how-do-i-replace-part-of-a-pattern-and-reference-a-variable-within-it

Comment: I used a different form of substitute command -line scoped. E.g - :1:$ s/.../.../g is what I quickly did to test. I guess you don't really need them, since you are substituting all.

Comment: OK I got it. It's more or less the one I want. Thank you very much! :)